# Getting error in accessing inherited class member

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java. I want to access extended(inherited class's data member in the base class using the object of base as well as derived class. But I am facing this error :
Syntax error on token "bonus", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token when trying to access member bonus using object of both base as well as derived class

This error goes away if I place the code of object creation and accessing inside public static void main method. I want to understand the reason for this?

```
public class DerivedClass{
    public int bonus = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
class BaseClass extends DerivedClass 
{
    BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
    b.bonus = 200; //error here
    d.bonus = 400; //error here
    System.out.println("bonus this year is:"+" "+ s.bonus);
}
```

Error message:

> Syntax error on token "bonus", VariableDeclaratorId expected after
>   this token

Comment: You've just put code directly into the class, not inside a constructor or a method.

Comment: Just a note, to avoid confusion you should name your classes accordingly. The base class - is an extendable class, the derived - is extending one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a method and you will see both work. You aren't allowed to write code blocks directly in the class body.

```
class BaseClass extends DerivedClass {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
        DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
        b.bonus = 200;
        d.bonus = 400;
    }
}
```

There are [initialisers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6), though they also have to be declared within `{}`.

```
{
    BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
    b.bonus = 200;
    d.bonus = 400;
}
```

The class body has a well-defined structure (field declarations, method declarations, block declarations). You simply should follow that structure.

> ### [8.1.6. Class Body and Member Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)
>
> A class body may contain declarations of members of the class, that is, fields (§8.3), methods (§8.4), classes (§8.5), and interfaces (§8.5).
>
> A class body may also contain instance initializers (§8.6), static initializers (§8.7), and declarations of constructors (§8.8) for the class.
>
> ```
> ClassBody:
>   { {ClassBodyDeclaration} }
>
> ClassBodyDeclaration:
>   ClassMemberDeclaration 
>   InstanceInitializer 
>   StaticInitializer 
>   ConstructorDeclaration
>
> ClassMemberDeclaration:
>   FieldDeclaration 
>   MethodDeclaration 
>   ClassDeclaration 
>   InterfaceDeclaration 
>   ;
> ```

Comment: I have already mentioned that.I know it will work inside main method.But I want to know why it doesn't work this way..

Comment: @user2156513: Because you can't put statements directly into a class declaration - only declarations. This has nothing to do with inheritance or variables - you'd see the same problem with `class Test { System.out.println("This won't work."); }`

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to write Statements directly in class body. You need to put them in a method.

Statements are not allowed means that any of the following are not allowed:

`Assignment expressions (aValue = 23.45;)
Any use of ++ or -- (aValue++;)
Method invocations (System.out.println("Hello World!");)
Object creation expressions (Car mycar = new Car();)`

Answer (score 0):

- You should read "Head First Java" book.
- In your code, you are trying to change state of object that's why you are getting the error. You can do such thing either in method Or in block.
- DerivedClass should call BaseClass and BaseClass should call DerivedClass (this is based on extends keyword.)
- Poor code(super class having main method.); I just removed compilation error, see the below code.

Hope, this will help you.

```
public class DerivedClass {
    public int bonus = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

class BaseClass extends DerivedClass {
    BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();
    // code in block
    {
        b.bonus = 200; // no here
        d.bonus = 400; // no here
        System.out.println("bonus this year is:" + " " + d.bonus); // fixed typo
    }
}
```